# How this lookup formula works?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like you to explain why this formula works: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A10=D2),B2:B10)`
I know about lookup, I know what this formula does (The following formula searches A2:A10 for the last instance of the value in D2, and returns the corresponding value from B2:B10...) but I don't understand how it works. For example what does this part do: A2:A10=D2 ?
Here is the source where you can find the workbook also: http://www.xl-central.com/lookup-last-instance.html

Comment: Have you selected the cell with the formula and used Formulas ► Formula Auditing ► Evaluate Formula?

Comment: Good hint, but did not helped too much. Actually it helped me understand the A2:A10=D2 part but not the others.
A2:A10=D2 basically goes over the cells in the range and applies the equality check on them then returns with a list of booleans according to the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LOOKUP(lookup_value,  lookup_vector,  [result_vector])
```

The [LOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/fil-ph/starter-help/lookup-function-HP010342671.aspx) is a very basic cousin of the [HLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/hlookup-function-HP010062411.aspx) and [VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx). The latter two provide additional functionality for selecting the row/column of data to return from their *table_array* parameter (*row_index_num/col_index_num*) as well as a *range_lookup* option which can force an exact match or an approximate (aka *nearest*) match when used with sorted data. The `LOOKUP` function has to have the *result_vector* (return row or column) specified if it is not the same as the *lookup_vector* and always returns the nearest match.

Excel treats TRUE as one and FALSE as zero when used mathematically. A *1* divided by *1* will equal *1* and a *1* divided by *0* is a `#DIV/0!` error. A `#DIV/0!` error will not match anything; not even another `#DIV/0!` error. Since you are looking for a *2*, it finds something that *might* be the best match in row 2 (e.g. 1/1) but keeps looking since it is not an exact match. It finds another possible in row 5 but keeps looking. It finds another possible in row 8 and cannot find anything remotely close below that so it returns the value from column B in row 8. We are looking to match a *2* with a series on *1*'s and errors because we want the last nearest match.

For all intents and purposes, you are breaking the rules when using this type of formula as the *lookup_vector* is not in ascending order (which conventionally it should be). With the unsorted duplicate values we are achieving the correct results by relying on the function's 'broken' behavior when looking for a value it will never find; e.g. looking for a *2* in an array of *1*'s and errors.

Comment: Excellent answer. +1 for "boken behaviour"